# shopify website takes a long time to load

Tags: ruby, shopify

url: http://bookpanda.pk/

The website takes too long to load the landing page. Even though the size of page is 1.97 MB, but the time it takes to load is around 8-9 seconds.

Can you please guide me where the problem persists and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

For such a general, high-level question, I can only provide an equivalently high-level, situationally relevant answer:

Use browser dev tools to diagnose at a high level. Check out the load times of each network call as well as their timings. Modern browsers also have performance profiling tools built in that help you find out where it's spending time or waiting for something else that's slow.

For example, here's a JS Flame Chart of the first 10 seconds of page load:

[image]